# How to retail variable in string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I hava a string that contain some variable

```
$str="$users[1]='us1';$users[2]='admin';";
fwrite($str);
```

I want to write string to file data.php 
but the result is
='us1';='admin';
**i want file data.php like this**

```
$users[1]='us1';$users[2]='admin';
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `"` will evaluate the PHP variables inside the string

You should use `'` instead like this:

```
$str='$users[1]=\'us1\';$users[2]=\'admin\';';
```

Your output will be: (as expected)

```
$users[1]='us1';$users[2]='admin';
```

---

or if you are okay with `"` inside the string, use it like this:

```
$str='$users[1]="us1";$users[2]="admin";';
```

Your output will be:

```
$users[1]="us1";$users[2]="admin";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try either using single quotes or escaping the `$` sign using a backslash. PHP tries to interpret $ variables in double quotes.

**EDIT**: As pointed out, actual code would help:

```
$str = "\$users[1]='us1';\$users[2]='admin';";
```

Since we're escaping the `$` signs, they will be literally interpreted, rather than executed.

Comment: It could be better if you explain this in programming language, you are the first one who picked the OP's problem quickly, the other ones just used your idea in a programming way, but still +1 for you :)

Comment: @Insomania the other one is just behind 10sec doesn't mean that he copied other person's idea.. it will take time to format a code, than just printing the statement

Comment: @Thamizhan I couldn't have said it better! this answer might have been posted first because it did not take much effort(before the edit)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\` for escape a character from reading by browser.

**Use:**

```
$str = "\$users[1]='us1';\$users[2]='admin';";
```

**Output**

> $users[1]='us1';$users[2]='admin';